# Prove that if $a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence then $\sqrt{a_n}$ is also Cauchy.

Tags: calculus

If $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence with : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; a_{n} \geq 1$. Then $(\sqrt{a_{n}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence as well.

How do I show $\vert \sqrt{a_{n}} - \sqrt{a_{m}}\vert < \varepsilon $?

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** Since $a_n\ge1$ we have

$$|\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{a_m}|=\frac{|a_n-a_m|}{|\sqrt{a_n}+\sqrt{a_m}|}\leq\frac{1}{2}|a_n-a_m|$$

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, then
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \leq \frac{1}{2} \quad\forall x\geq 1
$$
By the Mean-value theorem, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$.

Now show that if $(a_n)$ is cauchy, and $f$ is uniformly continuous, then $(f(a_n))$ is also Cauchy.

Comment: Isn't continuity enough? For a continuous $f$, $u_n$ Cauchy $\iff$ $u_n$ convergent $\implies$ $f(u_n)$ convergent $\implies$ $f(u_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: @arbautjc He uses **uniform** continuity, not (ordinary) continuity.

Comment: @tetori Yes, I know, and it's my question: isn't continuity enough? Of course, conituous on a compact $\implies$ uniformly continuous (and since $a_n$ is convergent, you can work on a compact), but it's not the point, I don't think we need this.

Comment: @arbautjc Oh, sorry. I misunderstood your comment.  
 Continuity is not enough condition. Consider $f:(0,\infty)\to\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)=1/x$, $a_n=1/n$. We know that $f$ is continuous and $a_n$ is Cauchy. But $f(a_n)$ is not Cauchy.

Comment: Of course, I mean, continuous, and limit of $a_n$ is in domain of continuity ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I can see two different ways of proving that $(\sqrt{a_{n}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence :

1. If $(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence such that : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; a_{n} \in I$ and $f \, : \, I \, \longrightarrow \, \mathbb{R}$ is *uniformly continuous*, then $(f(a_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is also a Cauchy sequence. To apply this here, remember that a Cauchy sequence is always bounded. In addition to this, you have : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; a_{n} \geq 1$. As a consequence, there exists $M \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ such that : $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \; a_{n} \in [1,M]$. Since $x \, \longmapsto \, \sqrt{x}$ is continuous on $[1,M]$, it follows from *Heine's theorem* that it is uniformly continuous on $[1,M]$. It proves that $(\sqrt{a_{n}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence.
2. You can also prove it directly. Notice that : $$\forall (n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^{2}, \; \displaystyle \vert \sqrt{a_{n}} - \sqrt{a_{m}} \vert \leq \frac{\vert a_{n}-a_{m} \vert}{\vert \sqrt{a_{n}} + \sqrt{a_{m}} \vert} \leq \frac{1}{2} \vert a_{n} - a_{m} \vert$$

Comment: Sorry, by the time I sent my answer, these ideas were already submitted.